# Is there a Cantor space that contains the interval?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, cantor-set

Cantor spaces are topological spaces which are compact, totally disconnected, and perfect. The prototypical example is the Cantor set equipped with the Euclidean topology, although other such examples exist.

Now consider the closed unit interval $X = [0,1]$. Although it is usually equipped with the Euclidean topology $\tau_{d}$, there are many other topologies that can be chosen for $X$ that can give the resulting topological space counter-intuitive properties.

Is there a topology $\tau$ for the closed unit interval such that $(X,\tau)$ is a Cantor space, and so that $\tau$ is finer than the Euclidean topology ($\tau_d \subseteq \tau$)? If not, is there a straightforward way of showing that such a thing is impossible?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "contains". In your example the interval is only contained setwise, but the topology is different than the standard one.

Comment: The second condition I mentioned can also be interpreted as saying that $\tau$ is a finer topology than the Euclidean topology on the interval.

Comment: Your first statement (*"Cantor set is the only Cantor space"*) is only correct for metrizable spaces (and, to be accurate, the space has to be non-empty). For non-metrizable spaces the double arrow space without the minimal and maximal element is compact, totally disconnected and has no isolated points.

Comment: @Ulli Good catch—I’ll make the appropriate edit to the post.

Comment: It should also be noted that the above definition of *Cantor space* differs from [the usual one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure whether this is what you had in mind, since with this new formulation the answer is (almost trivially) "no": Since $(X, \tau)$ is compact, there is no strictly coarser Hausdorff topology on $X$. Hence $\tau_d = \tau$. Hence $\tau$ is not totally disconnected.

Following the above discussion, didn't you want to know whether there is a finer topology $\tau$, such that $(X, \tau)$ is an *open* subspace (or any subspace?) of the Cantor *set* (up to homeomorphism)? Or of a (not necessarily metrizable)  Cantor *space*?

Comment: Your response (as far as I can tell) answers my question. Although the other questions are interesting and are perhaps far less trivial, my confusion in assuming that the previous version of the question was equivalent to this one seems to have already caused enough turbulence that such conversations warrant being tabled for another separate post. I appreciate your help, nonetheless.

Comment: Glad, that we could solve it, finally.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tau$ be the Euclidean topology on $[0, 1]$ and $\mu = \{U \cup T: U \in \tau, T \subset \mathbb Q\}$. Obviously, $\mu$ is a topology on $[0, 1]$, which is finer than $\tau$.
$\{[u, v]: u,v \in \mathbb Q\} \cup \{\{q\}\}: q \in \mathbb Q\}$ is a countable, clopen base of $\mu$. Hence, $\mu$ is metrizable, separable and zero-dimensional. Therefore, it is homeomorphic to a subspace of $2^\omega$, which is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Note that this subspace is not open in the Cantor set, since it contains isolated points. 
Of course, the analogous construction works with the open interval $(0, 1)$ as well.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio: Not really: I realized the finer topology as a subspace of the Cantor set, hence of a totally disconnected, compact and perfect topological space. But, yes, not as an *open* subspace, see my note. I understood the OP's question that he is not looking for an *open* subspace? In fact, with Baire category theorem it's not difficult to show that such an *open* subspace cannot exist. I remember that I have seen an answer here in this direction, which was deleted later. I have no idea, why? I thought this was just for the reason that the OP is looking for a non-open subspace?

Comment: But I agree: the question is very unclear: open or not open? What does "contain" mean?  Certainly never used in topology in this sense.  Dear @aghostinthefigures: can you please reformulate your question without the word "contain"? (Or only in the usual topological meaning, namely as a subspace.) For instance, are you looking for a finer topology on $[0,1]$, which is homeomorphic to a subspace of the Cantor set (then my answer provides an example), or homeomorphic to an open subspace? Then it does not exist by Baire category theorem. Or something else?

Comment: Ok, indeed, you may be right. But I would still like to wait for the OP's clarification, since it's so strange. If then still necessary, I will post a proof that it cannot exist. But, sorry, not today anymore.

Comment: @Ulli It seems that my description of what I'm asking is inconsistent or at least worded in a very confusing way, so I will try to rethink how to formulate the problem and edit the question accordingly for clarity.

Comment: The edits have now been made to hopefully clarify the nature of the question.

Comment: Although this example does not answer the intended question of the OP, I will keep it, since it might be interesting for other users visiting this post. Hope that's ok?